# keyword rotation is not recognized (Pandas Profiling)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I am trying to use pandas_profiling package for data profiling. For basic usage, i have followed this documentation

https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling

and use the following code from it

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling

df = pd.DataFrame(
np.random.rand(100, 5),
columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
)

df.profile_report(style={'full_width':True})
```

But upon running this code in Anaconda I am getting following error

*ValueError: keyword rotation is not recognized; valid keywords are ['size', 'width', 'color', 'tickdir', 'pad', 'labelsize', 'labelcolor', 'zorder', 'gridOn', 'tick1On', 'tick2On', 'label1On', 'label2On', 'length', 'direction', 'left', 'bottom', 'right', 'top', 'labelleft', 'labelbottom', 'labelright', 'labeltop']*

Comment: the code you have posted works fine for me in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Can you tell me why i am getting this error , as i have already installed all the libraries

Comment: what is the version ? I am testing on `pandas_profiling.__version__`: `2.3.0` and pandas version `pd.__version__` : `0.25.3` , cannot reproduce the error

Comment: Please post the output of `pd.show_versions()`

Comment: pandas==0.23.4,
pandas-profiling==2.3.0,
matplotlib==3.1.2

Comment: @anky_91 can you tell me what's the version of matplotlib you are using

Comment: @UsmanRafiq `'3.1.0'`

Comment: I can try updating my pandas package

Comment: @anky_91
pandas==0.23.4, pandas-profiling==2.3.0, matplotlib==3.1.2
These are not working for me still

Comment: @anky_91 It worked for me after i upgrade my package same as yours , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference: update your pandas and matplotlib packages. Versions of pandas-profiling later than 2.4.0 will automatically update these packages.